# gene dosage vs copy number

Tags: terminology, genomes, copy-number-variation

In the online articles I'm reading, I see the authors mention **gene dosage** and **copy number**. My confusion is regarding if the two terms mean exactly the same thing - number of copies a gene occur in the genome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't always mean the same thing, as gene dosage may be measured by RNA-Seq, whereas copy number by DNA sequencing / other means. But people do use it as rough substitutes. Often people do try to infer copy number from RNA-Seq, as samples tend to fall in "digital" intervals of expression, and use CNV to estimate gene dosage.